# Issue in printing a right angle triangle in Python

Tags: python, arrays, variables, multidimensional-array

I am trying to learn Python basics. I am designing a code that would print a triangle, code posted below. The expected output of the program must be a triangle from the right side not from the left which part of the code to modify to get the expected output.

The output of the program should not be like below

[image]

I want the output to be like this

[image]

Any help on this is highly appreciated. Thanks

```
while True:
  n = int(input("enter a number between 0 and 10:"))
  if 0 <= n <= 10:
    break
  print('try again')

rows = n
for num in range(rows+1):
  for i in range(1, num+1):
      if num % 2 == 0:
        #print(end="" '#')
        print('#',end="")
      else:
        #print(num)  
        print(num,end="")  

print(" ")
```

Comment: Can you put a real example of what you want to get and not just a text explaining ?

Comment: I have modified the question posted @BradFigueroa Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use a `list` to create the elements (when it's an odd number just append the value in number times otherwise character '#' number times as the description said )of the triangle and then use a `for` loop to print them as below:

```
while True:
  n = int(input("enter a number between 0 and 10:"))
  if 0 <= n <= 10:
    break
  print('try again')

result = [idx*'#' if idx % 2 == 0 else f'{idx}'*idx  for idx in range(1, n+1) ]
for i in range(len(result)):
    print(' '*(n-i-1), result[i])
```

The result would be:

```
      1
     ##
    333
   ####
  55555
```

Hope this can help you :)

Answer (score -1):

Checking your code with the input (5) gives the output (1##333####55555 )

but the following code for the same input (5) gives the output (55555####333##1  )

```
while True:
  n = int(input("enter a number between 0 and 10:"))
  if 0 <= n <= 10:
    break
  print('try again')

rows = n
for num in range(rows, 0,-1):
  for i in range(num+1, 1,-1):
      if num % 2 == 0:
        #print(end="" '#')
        print('#',end="")
      else:
        #print(num)  
        print(num,end="")  

print(" ")
```

Hope this answer your question

Comment: Code-only answers are rarely helpful to the general community, A good answer should include an explanation.